# Detect faces from "Where's Waldo" picture using OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, image-recognition

I want to detect all faces from an "Where's Waldo" image just like in [this](https://youtu.be/-i7HMPpxB-Y?t=23) video (at 23 seconds), using OpenCV. I already tried using all the haar classifiers OpenCV provides, but I don't get any results. Probably because the classifiers are specified for human faces, not cartoon faces. Is the only solution for this to create a new haar classifier or are there other ways?

[image: Here is a screenshot from the video]

Comment: Where is the code you have written?

Comment: @Jaba I used the code from this gist: https://gist.github.com/tilfin/98bbba47fdc4ac10c4069cce5fabd834

Comment: You should know that simply drawn face lack important information required by most face recognition algorithms.

Answer (score 1):

The haar cascade your using is for (any) face detection. As Klaus mentioned, that is not the same as face recognition.

If you want, you can [train your own haar cascade](https://docs.opencv.org/3.3.1/dc/d88/tutorial_traincascade.html) but it might be overkill for what you're trying to achieve. I'd suggest going for [template matching](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_template_matching/py_template_matching.html)

[image: mario coins detected in mario level using opencv template matching]

In fact, doing a quick search I easily found this article: [Using OpenCV, Python and Template Matching to play “Where’s Waldo?”](https://machinelearningmastery.com/using-opencv-python-and-template-matching-to-play-wheres-waldo/)

[image: template matching finding waldo]

Here's another article that using TensorFlow: [How to Find Wally with a Neural Network](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-find-wally-neural-network-eddbb20b0b90)

[image: finding waldo using tensorflow]

I recommending starting simple with [opencv matchTemplate](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/imgproc/doc/object_detection.html?highlight=matchtemplate#cv2.matchTemplate) first.

Comment: The link to where's waldo with template-matching is dead but there is a  [backup-copy on archive.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20170918035306/https://machinelearningmastery.com/using-opencv-python-and-template-matching-to-play-wheres-waldo/)